# Specify two meta description based on browser language

Tags: html, meta-tags, google-search-console

I want to specify two meta description based on browser language. One is english. Another one is japanese. I tried two ways in the following below:

1:

```
<head>
   <meta
      name="description"
      lang="en-us"
      content="Explore new opportunity."
    />
    <meta
      name="description"
      lang="ja-jp"
      content="ダンサー。"
    />
</head>
```

2:

```
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      const isJapanese = window.navigator.language.toLowerCase() === 'ja-jp' || window.navigator.language.toLowerCase() === 'ja' ;
      var description= isJapanese ? "ダンサー。" : "Explore new opportunity.";

      console.log(description);
<meta
      name="description"
      lang="en-us"
      content=description
    />
    <meta
      name="description"
      lang="ja-jp"
      content=description
    />

</script>
</head>
```

But there is no luck. It always show english meta description even if browser language is japanes. Any helps?

Comment: I think document.head.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content = description; would be the one liner u need.

Comment: @JackSparrow, That is work for me. Thanks . Also document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content = description work for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Posting it as answer, so you can mark it as solution if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your variant #2, you need an one liner that updates the meta content description as follows:

```
document.head.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content = description;
```